# Newey-West error for multiple linear regressions

Tags: r, regression, lapply, standard-error

I have a data frame with 126 columns and want to run linear regressions over all columns. I did this with the lapply() function:

```
my_lms <- lapply(1:126, function(x) df[,x] ~ df$x1))
```

Again with the lapply() function I get the summary statistics:

```
lapply(my_lms, summary)
```

My question is how to get the same summary statistics using Newey-West errors?

I tried:

```
coeftest(my_lms, vcov. = NeweyWest)
```

but this gives me the error message:
*Error in UseMethod("estfun") : 
  no applicable method for 'estfun' applied to an object of class "list"*

Thanks

Comment: `lapply(my_lms, coeftest, vcov. = NeweyWest)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stephane is exactly right, but I thought writing an explanatio nmight be needed. Your `my_lms` object is a list with each item in the list being a nested-object with the proper class for the `coeftest` function. However, the coeftest function doesn't have the machinery for serial extraction for the "master list". So you need to use `lapply` again with the `coeftest` being the functional argument. Extra parameters can be passed to `coeftest` using `lappy`'s "triple dots" mechanism: Quoted material from the `?lapply` page

> Usage
>
> lapply(X, FUN, ...)

```
lapply(my_lms, coeftest, vcov. = NeweyWest)
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer!